# Selecting the first and last occurance of a tag in all the html by CSS selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html tags

```
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Last</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I want to change the background of the first li and last li across all over the html tags. How can I do that?

I used this css by it doesn't work as I expected

```
li:first-child {
  background: #900
}

li:last-child {
  background: #900
}
```

p.s I need the solution works on IE8+.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kx43rwxk/)

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML output?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this without JS for all use cases. But this works for you example : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gu2sqctc/

Comment: I think you would need JS for this purely because you need IE8 support.

Comment: Is the HTML structure dynamic or is what you're showing all it's ever going to be?

Comment: @Harry I meant that a way which is supported by IE8 currently

Comment: @AmericanSlime The structure is static (but it is just a sample)

Comment: Just to note, `:last-child` is not supported in IE8 so a purely CSS solution will not work.

Comment: @RezaRahmati: Yes, that is why I said you need JS. `last-child`, `last-of-type` selectors are not supported by IE8.

Comment: Cool, I'm wondering why he marked the answer below as being correct if he wanted IE8 support.

Comment: For :first-child to work in IE8 and earlier, a <!DOCTYPE> must be declared. I assumed this was the case for last-child as well, but I guess it doesn't apply.

Comment: @PaulRedmond because I had accepted that before your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IE8 support in mind, a jQuery solution would be best IMO:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMBxYO

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol:first li:first, ol:last li:last').css('background', 'pink');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your HTML structure won't change, you could do:

```
div:first-child li:first-child {
    background: #900;}

div:last-child li:last-child {
    background: #900;}
```

Comment: it seems that last-child is not supported in ie8 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/

Comment: Yeah I realize that now, sorry. I don't know if you control the HTML, but maybe you could just add a class or id to the last li and target it that way. Or if you knew how many you had, you could use the `+` to keep targeting siblings all the way down.